# How to use auto route with scrollable view in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am using Flutter to create a Web app.
How can i create a `layout_view` using the package `auto_route` that can be scrolled with a single scroll parent. In a way that i don't need to add scroll views on child and create multiple scroll points and bars.

I did something like this:

```dart
Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Constants.backgroundColor,
        body: CustomScrollView(
          primary: true,
          slivers: <Widget>[
            SliverAppBar(
              expandedHeight: Responsive.isSmallScreen(context) ? 93 : 196.0,
              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
              flexibleSpace: const FlexibleSpaceBar(
                background: AppBarView(),
              ),
            ),
            SliverFillRemaining(
              hasScrollBody: true,
              child: Column(
                children: const [
                  Expanded(child: AutoRouter()),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      )
```

The problem is that if the `AutoRouter` is bigger than the remained viewport the bottom is overflowed and i can't scroll. I tried to add `SingleChildScrollView` as parent of AutoRouter but it doesn't render
I don't want to repeat the `AppBarView` on all screens, that's why i am using a layout view with an auto router. But at the same time i want to scroll de AppBar along with the rest of the screen.

[ ]'s